# Orion installation trough Chef Recipes and Blueprints in FIWARE Lab

Tags: chef-recipe, fiware-orion, fiware

I was trying to install [Orion](http://catalogue.fi-ware.org/enablers/publishsubscribe-context-broker-orion-context-broker/creating-instances) though Chef Recipes in [FIWARE Lab](https://cloud.lab.fi-ware.org/) (creating a new template) but I couldn't find the package in the list.

Also, while trying to run it cloning a blueprint template that already exists, it returns an error (image can't be found). I've also realised that in the blueprint template, the Orion Context Broker version is outdated (0.13.0).

Could somebody perform this actions without errors? Is it under maintenance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes It was under maintenance. Now you should be able to create templates with orion and clone the predefined templates.
Sorry for any inconvenience.